# Referencing file from method in python

Tags: python, tk-toolkit

I need some help with this. I am using this method to help me open a file with a dialog box:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

fileOpen = Tk()
fileOpen.withdraw() #hiding tkinter window

file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(
title="Open file", filetypes=[("txt file",".txt"),("All files",".*")])

if file_path != "":
    print "you chose file with path:", file_path

else:
    print "you didn't open anything!"

print file_path
```

It works fine, and the file is opened in Python, but I don't know how to make further commands on that file, for example if I wanted to read it or write on it.
I have tried referencing it as fileOpen, but that doesn't seem to work, and I have no idea what the variable would be instead.

Answer (score 5):

The file is not opened at all. To open it, call `open(file_path)`. That gives you an object your can `read` from or `write` to. Please read the Python tutorial's [section on file I/O](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: I'm familiar with those methods, but the thing is, I need to be able to choose any file I want, not just one specific file. How would I do that?

Comment: @jesusu2: you open the file with `open(file_path)`.